# How to change the background color of customize checkbox in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I was created a customized checkbox using tailwind(as a component in react project). Now I want to change the background color of the checkbox before it is checked and after it is checked.
This is what I want:
[image]

This is current look:
[image]

I want to know how to change this color in **tailwind.css**
This is checkbox code:

```html
<div className="check-box">
    <input type="checkbox"
         value={ value }
         id={ id }
         name={ name }
         onBlur={ onBlur }
         className="absolute h-6 w-6 cursor-pointer" onChange={ onChange } />
                    
     <div className="bg-xaplink_gray_1 border-2 border-   xaplink_gray_3 w-6 h-6 flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center mr-2 focus-within:border-xaplink_black_2">
        <svg className="fill-current hidden w-4 h-4 text-xaplink_white pointer-events-none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 17 12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
              <g transform="translate(-9 -11)" fill="#FFFF" fillRule="nonzero">
                  <path d="m25.576 11.414c0.56558 0.55188 0.56558 1.4439 0 1.9961l-9.404 9.176c-0.28213 0.27529-0.65247 0.41385-1.0228 0.41385-0.37034 0-0.74068-0.13855-1.0228-0.41385l-4.7019-4.588c-0.56584-0.55188-0.56584-1.4442 0-1.9961 0.56558-0.55214 1.4798-0.55214 2.0456 0l3.679 3.5899 8.3812-8.1779c0.56558-0.55214 1.4798-0.55214 2.0456 0z" />
              </g>
          </g>
         </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my checkbox component in react:

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState }  from "react";
const XCheckBox = ({ value, id, name, onBlur,label, side, error, touched, onChange }) => {
    
    return (
        <>
           <div className=" flex flex-row gap-5 py-2">
               <div className="check-box">
                   <input type="checkbox"
                          value={ value }
                          id={ id }
                          name={ name }
                          onBlur={ onBlur }
                          className="absolute h-6 w-6 cursor-pointer" onChange={ onChange } />
                    <div className="bg-xaplink_gray_1 border-2 border-xaplink_gray_3 w-6 h-6 flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center mr-2 focus-within:border-xaplink_black_2">
                        <svg className="fill-current hidden w-4 h-4 text-xaplink_white pointer-events-none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 17 12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g fill="none" fillRule="evenodd">
                                <g transform="translate(-9 -11)" fill="#FFFF" fillRule="nonzero">
                                    <path d="m25.576 11.414c0.56558 0.55188 0.56558 1.4439 0 1.9961l-9.404 9.176c-0.28213 0.27529-0.65247 0.41385-1.0228 0.41385-0.37034 0-0.74068-0.13855-1.0228-0.41385l-4.7019-4.588c-0.56584-0.55188-0.56584-1.4442 0-1.9961 0.56558-0.55214 1.4798-0.55214 2.0456 0l3.679 3.5899 8.3812-8.1779c0.56558-0.55214 1.4798-0.55214 2.0456 0z" />
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                { touched && error ? (
                    <p className="text-xs pl-2 text-xaplink_red_2 mb-4">{ error }</p>
                ) : null }
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default XCheckBox;
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the class accent-color

> Use the accent-{color} utilities to change the accent color of an
> element. This is helpful for styling elements like checkboxes and
> radio groups by overriding the browser’s default color.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="accent-pink-300" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Use text colour to change the check mark when checked and bg when unchecked  like this

```
className="absolute h-6 w-6 accent-gray-700  bg-grey-700 text-red-500  rounded cursor-pointer"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear that you want to just change the background color of the checkbox, or remove its check sign.

Anyway, the default style for the checkbox input contains the check sign and you can create custom inputs for your needs.

If you want to remove the check sign, you can create a custom checkbox, using the below sandbox.
[Custom checkbox without check sign](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-tailwind-input-forked-uyhzt?file=/src/styles.css:0-1050)

And if you want to have a check sign, you can implement follow styles with tailwindCss, based on your theme. [Custom checkbox with check sign](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-checkbox-forked-qe594)

Comment: No, I wanna change the background color with the check sign. You have used CSS. But In my project, I have used tailwind.css I want to know how I can change the background color using tailwind.

Comment: You can use @tailwindcss/forms plugin, if you want. Here is its [related sample](https://play.tailwindcss.com/TvjY5NyGgv). 

But if you do not want to use this plugin, you should change the style using CSS (since it needs to change the `:after` pseudo-element.)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
className="absolute h-6 w-6 accent-gray-700 cursor-pointer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Accent doesn't work for me either but in your css you can override this:

```
[type=checkbox]:checked {
background-image: none; /*to remove the tickmark when checked*/
background-color: #1e3; /* change the color when checked */`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    className="checked:bg-sky-700"
    checked={true}
/>
```